# What is the page size for 32 and 64 bit versions of windows Os?

Tags: windows, memory-management, virtual-memory

I want to know the default page size for virtual memory in windows Os for both 32 and 64 bit versions. For ex: the page size of **Linux** (x86) is **4 Kb**.

Answer (score 11):

call [`GetSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx) or better [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340(v=vs.85).aspx) and look for *dwPageSize* member of [`SYSTEM_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. however now under windows in both x86 and x64 page size is `0x1000` or `4Kb`